# php wordpress function returning Warning: Missing argument 1

Tags: wordpress, function, warnings, mamp

I wrote this couples of functions, that alternate a exploded Custom Field string with the post permalink:

(where the Custom Field should look like this: ex. Google++http//:google.com")

```
// Custom Permalink
function custom_permalink($url){
    global $post;
    $link = get_post_meta($post->ID,'link',true);
    if ($link) {
        $pieces = explode("++", $link);
        $url = $pieces[1];
    } else {
        $url = the_permalink();
    }
    return $url;
}

// Via Text
function via_text($url){
    global $post;
    $link = get_post_meta($post->ID,'link',true);
    if ($link) {
        $pieces = explode("++", $link);
        $url = ' <span><a href="'.$pieces[1].'">Via '.$pieces[0].'</a></span>';
    } else {
        $url = ' ';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

... which work all right when tested on a MAMP server, but when deployed they return:

"Warning: Missing argument 1"

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Try to see at which line does this warning occur.

Comment: Turn on `WP_DEBUG` on your MAMP, see what it gives: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I figured it out...
this happens when a class gets instantiated and theres no default argument for the constructor...

here are the working functions...

```
    // Custom Permalink
    function custom_permalink($url='') {
        global $post;
        $link = get_post_meta($post->ID,'link',true);
        if ($link) {
            $pieces = explode("++", $link);
            $url = $pieces[1];
        } else {
            $url = the_permalink();
        }
        return $url;
    }

    // Via Text
    function via_text($url='') {
        global $post;
        $link = get_post_meta($post->ID,'link',true);
        if ($link) {
            $pieces = explode("++", $link);
            $url = ' <span><a href="'.$pieces[1].'">Via '.$pieces[0].'</a></span>';
        } else {
            $url = ' ';
        }
        return $url;
    }
```

in case anyone is in need...
what they do:

in case theres a post with the Custom Field 'link' (like so: Google++http://google.com) the function will replace the permalink with the Custom Link. So in the theme call: echo custom_permalink(); ... instead of the_permalink();

the via_text() function works a little different; it calls a span tag with the Custom Field 'link' exploded like so:

```
     <span><a href="http://google.com">Via Google</a></span>
```

hope this works for somebody else

:)